# how to enable editText cut/copy/paste functionality in android?

Tags: android

please don't mark this question as duplicate ,as this thing only working in one edittext which inputtype set as phone ,but it is not working in other edittext case here is my edittext that is working

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin_15"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"

            android:hint="Mobile Number"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:id="@+id/ed_phone"/>
```

and one of other that s not working

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/ed_userName"/>
```

here is my App theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#46C203</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

    </style>
```

Now i have tried many ways to work this default copy/paste functioning, didn't find solution that worked for me
Any help would be appreciable

Comment: where are you showing the editext? in popup?

Comment: no in activity layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally got the solution i was using this method for hiding my keyboard for touching outside editext

```
 @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        View view = getCurrentFocus();
        boolean ret = super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);

        if (view instanceof EditText) {
            View w = getCurrentFocus();
            int scrcoords[] = new int[2];
            w.getLocationOnScreen(scrcoords);
            float x = event.getRawX() + w.getLeft() - scrcoords[0];
            float y = event.getRawY() + w.getTop() - scrcoords[1];

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                    && (x < w.getLeft() || x >= w.getRight()
                    || y < w.getTop() || y > w.getBottom()) ) {

                ((EditText)view).setError(null);
                view.clearFocus();
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

here i just need to comment this line

```
view.clearFocus();
```

and now it works

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in your edit text :-

```
   android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

so your edittext will be like this :-

```
      <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:hint="mail"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/ed_userName"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
```

Hope it may help you . :)

Comment: now my  keyboard is not opening for type ,its not working

Comment: @pkgrover change your activity tag in maniefest :-   <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible">

Comment: It opens keyboard only first time when i open my activity , but not after that, by the way ,menu appear of cut/copy/paste appear first time ,but they are not function after i clicked any of them

Answer (score 0):

The text you are trying to paste (from clipboard) should be a valid email address since you specified input type as email address, otherwise it would not work. all the best :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add this attribute to your EditText :

```
 android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: my keyboard is not opening for typing ,its not working